# MySQL : select tags where tag=x

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have tables media, tags, tag_content

**c_ media**

```
mid (primary)
m_title (varchar)
m_date (int 11, unix timestamp) index
```

**tags**

```
t_id (primary)
t_name (varchar)
t_type (varchar)

key: tag (columns t_name, t_type)
```

**tag_content**

```
tc_id (int 11) (same as t_id from tags table)
tc_cid (int 11) (same as mid from c_media table)
key: tc (columns tc_id, tc_cid)
```

the goal is to get top tags from stories which also have a common tag (in this case 162) and were created within the last 24 hours. This seems to work but is slow, thanks for your help.

```
SELECT t_id, t_name, t_type, COUNT(t2.tc_id) AS total_tags FROM c_media
INNER JOIN tag_content t1 ON t1.tc_cid = mid AND t1.tc_id = '162'
INNER JOIN tag_content t2 ON t2.tc_cid = t1.tc_cid AND t2.tc_id != t1.tc_id
LEFT JOIN tags ON t_id = t2.tc_id
WHERE m_date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP( now( ) -86400 ) 
AND t_type NOT IN ('Topic', 'Position')
GROUP BY t2.tc_id
ORDER BY total_tags DESC
LIMIT 30
```

Comment: What do you mean by "slow"? How big are the tables? Do `tags` and `tag_content` have indexes?

Comment: tags is about 229,313 rows and tags_content is  ~2,202,004 total.

Comment: tags has an index (tag) it combines columns t_name and t_type) and tag_content has index tc (columns tc_id and tc_cid). the query sometimes takes 100 seconds plus.

Comment: Please post and `EXPLAIN` of a sample query.  Why not use the `TIMESTAMP` data type for the date column?  It's basically an unsigned 4 byte integer internally, but has helpful extras that make it useful.

Comment: Just kind of grew comfortable using unix timestamp. here is a screenshot of explain http://www.efabula.com/i/tmp-sql-explain.jpg